# How to use PHP 5.6 variadic function arguments with Symfony 2.8?

Tags: php, symfony

I have service method with variadic arguments:

```
public function callSP($namespace, $function, ...$params) {}
```

which is compiled into container like :

```
public function callSP($namespace, $function, $params = null)
```

so it causes :

> Strict Standards notice saying that callSP() should be compatible with XXX\XXX\Service::callSP($namespace, $function, ...$params)

Can't find even any questions about that.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but symfony doesn't support variadic arguments. To get around this, I'd suggest using *func_get_args()*.

Comment: The variadic arguments are not about Symfony, it's pure PHP. Are you extending the service somewhere? How do you call this method or service? Give me some more code so I could help.

Comment: I've just created a simple service:
    public function testMethod($firstArg, ...$additional)
 {
  var_dump($firstArg);
  var_dump($additional);
 }

Then in the controller I have
    $testService = $this->get('test');
    $testService->testMethod('1', '2', '3');

And it's normally dumping:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/frghtb7g9cp95fo/Zrzut%20ekranu%202016-07-25%2008.23.45.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes @RafałMnich, it is working but it is throwing notices ( we have strict rules for live env) , as it is compiled by Symfony with different signature, But Thanks anyway !

Comment: Cant figure out what is the actual case. When do your services compile into container? As far as I know services itself should not be compiled into container, only their definitions.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose, that problem occures for some kind of lazy service (listener, or explicit `lazy: true`)

Lazy services are operated with `ocramius/proxy-manager` library.

This library introduced support for variadic parameters since version 2.0, which requires at least PHP 7.0.

So I think there is nothing to do with 5.6 here.

Links:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/lazy_services.html
- https://github.com/Ocramius/ProxyManager/releases/tag/2.0.0
- https://github.com/Ocramius/ProxyManager/issues/307